# How do I use this JavaScript variable in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I'm trying to make a simple page that asks you for your name, and then uses name.length (JavaScript)  to figure out how long your name is.

This is my code so far:

```
<script>
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
var lengthOfName = name.length
</script>
<body>
</body>
```

I'm not quite sure what to put within the body tags so that I can use those variables that I stated before. I realize that this is probably a really beginner level question, but I can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: Can you at least provide the HTML you want to use, identifying where you would like this variable's value to go?

Comment: I didn't quite know what I wanted, so I described to the best of my abilities. Sorry!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You don't "use" JavaScript variables in HTML.  HTML is not a programming language, it's a markup language, it just "describes" what the page should look like.

If you want to display a variable on the screen, this is done with JavaScript.

First, you need somewhere for it to write to:

```
<body>
    <p id="output"></p>
</body>
```

Then you need to update your JavaScript code to write to that `<p>` tag.  Make sure you do so *after* the page is ready.

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
    var name = prompt("What's your name?");
    var lengthOfName = name.length

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = lengthOfName;
};
</script>
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var name = prompt("What's your name?");
  var lengthOfName = name.length

  document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = lengthOfName;
};
```

```html
<p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! So I would put the script after the body tags?

Comment: @Joseph: Script tags normally go in the `<head>`.  `window.onload` binds an event so that the code won't run until the page is loaded.

Comment: Okay, thanks! Best answer :) But if I were to remove that window.onload and put it in the beginning, would that change anything?

Comment: @Joseph: That would change *everything*!  When the browser loads your page, it starts from the top down.  So, if you remove `window.onload`, then it would try to write to the `<p>` tag before it exists.  You *could* remove the `window.onload`, if and only if you put the script tag after the `<body>`.  I prefer to keep my scripts in the `<head>`.

Comment: mind to run script innerHTML part after all html loads!

Answer (score 11):

You can create a `<p>` element:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script>
  var name = prompt("What's your name?");
  var lengthOfName = name.length
  p = document.createElement("p");
  p.innerHTML = "Your name is "+lengthOfName+" characters long.";
  document.body.appendChild(p);
  </script>
  <body>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. The code snippet runner within StackOverflow seems like it works. I'm wondering how that works; I was thinking about writing it so that it was like "Your name is x characters long".

Comment: I can fix that for you easily. This works by creating a paragraph element within the javascript, adding the text, and adding the element to the page.

Comment: So how would I do that?

Answer (score 8):

You can create an element with an id and then assign that length value to that element.

```js
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
var lengthOfName = name.length
document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = lengthOfName;
```

```html
<p id='message'></p>
```

Comment: `.value` won't exist on a `<p>`, only `input`.  PS I'm not the downvoter, this answer is easily fixed and then is a correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Hi there<span id="username"></span>!</h1>
    <script>
       let userName = prompt("What is your name?");
       document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = userName;
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<body>
    <div id="divMsg"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var name = prompt("What's your name?");
    var lengthOfName = name.length;
    document.getElementById("divMsg").innerHTML = "Length: " + lengthOfName;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use js variables inside html. To add the content of the javascript variable to the html use innerHTML() or create any html tag, add the content of that variable to that created tag and append that tag to the body or any other existing tags in the html.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML tags that you want to edit is called the DOM (Document object manipulate), you can edit the DOM with many functions in the document global object.

The best example that would work on almost any browser is the `document.getElementById`, it's search for html tag with that id set as an attribute.

There is another option which is easier but works only on modern browsers (IE8+), the querySelector function, it's will find the first element with the matched selector (CSS selectors).

Examples for both options:

```html
<script>
var name = prompt("What's your name?");
var lengthOfName = name.length
</script>
<body>
  <p id="a"></p>
  <p id="b"></p>
  <script>
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = name;
document.querySelector('#b').innerHTML = name.length;</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could get away with something as short as this:

```
<script>
  const name = prompt("What's your name?") ?? "";
  document.write(`<p>${name.length}</p>`);
</script>
```

It's not a very clean way of doing it but using `document.write` is not much worse than calling `prompt()` as soon as the page loads.

A more user-friendly approach  would be to have an actual text input on the page and to dynamically update the length as they type using an event listener.

```html
<label>Name: <input id="name-input"></label><br>
Length: <output id="name-length-output" for="name-input">0<output>

<script type="module">
    const nameInput = document.getElementById("name-input");
    const nameLengthOutput = document.getElementById("name-length-output");

    nameInput.addEventListener("input", e => {
        nameLengthOutput.textContent = nameInput.value.length;
    });
</script>
```

If you want to learn how to manipulate pages with JavaScript, the Mozilla Developer Network has a good tutorial about the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Comment: I wouldn't actually suggest using `document.write`.  You should be using `.innerHTML` (or `.appendChild`).  I guess it's ok if the script is running *before* the page is fully loaded, but once the page is fully loaded, `document.write` will erase the whole page.

Comment: [More reasons not to use document.write](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @Tom That link pretty much confirms my thoughts, innerHTML is almost as bad as document.write.