# Javascript/html in gitlab wiki page?

Tags: javascript, gitlab, wiki

I'm afraid I don't really have an idea how to do this - I want to use variables in a Gitlab Wiki page. is this possible at all using html? Can I run scripts on a page?

For example, this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035932/how-do-i-use-this-javascript-variable-in-html) on using a javascript variable in html - would something like this be possible?

For my specific example, I want a page with a table where the first column is numbers, and I want to take the largest value and display it at the top of the page. So for example the table might have rows like:

```
1   X
22  Y
15  Z
```

So at the top of the page I would display "largest number is 22". Does this make sense?

Comment: You cannot have a script in your Wikipage, since they sanitize the HTML (See what they allow [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/html-pipeline/1.11.0/HTML/Pipeline/SanitizationFilter#WHITELIST-constant)). To do what you want, you could generate that page in Gitlab-CI as part of your project's deploy pipeline, using whatever rendering engine and putting that variable in there, and update it automatically using Gitlab's [Wiki APIs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/wikis.html)

Comment: @blex shouldn't your comment be an answer?

Comment: @UlysseBN I feel like an answer should have more details of implementation. I don't have time to do that right now, maybe someone else will :)

Comment: I finally took some time to do it. Hope this helps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot have a script in your Wikipage, since they sanitize the HTML (See what they allow [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/html-pipeline/1.11.0/HTML/Pipeline/SanitizationFilter#WHITELIST-constant)). To do what you want, you could generate that page in Gitlab-CI as part of your project's deploy pipeline, using whatever rendering engine and putting that variable in there, and update it automatically using [Gitlab's Wiki APIs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/wikis.html).

## How to

I created a demo NodeJS project [here](https://gitlab.com/blex41/project-with-wiki-update), which, when I push to the `master` branch, auto-generates the [Wiki pages](https://gitlab.com/blex41/project-with-wiki-update/wikis/home). You can look at the code to see how it works.

This example app exposes a function to get a list of fruit and quantities in stock. We'll automatically add that data in the Wiki.

### Step 1 - Create page templates

You can add templates to your project for your Wiki pages. In my example, I used [MustacheJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mustache). And I put everything in a `wiki` folder (see folder structure at the end of step 5). Your template can look something like this:

**wiki/templates/home.mst**

```
# Welcome to the supermarket

The biggest quantity we have in stock is for **{{topProduct.label}}**,
with a total of **{{topProduct.stock}}**!

|   Fruit   |   Quantity   |
|-----------|--------------|
{{#inventory}}
| {{label}} | {{stock}} |
{{/inventory}}
```

In this example, the data will come from the project code itself.

### Step 2 - Build your pages

> **Note:** The scripts I wrote as a demo use `axios` to make requests to the Gitlab API, `mustache` to render the pages, and `qs` to format the data as a query string before posting it to Gitlab. You can use other ones or install them as dev dependencies:
> **`npm install --save-dev axios mustache qs`**

Create a js file which will get the data from your app, and render the templates into a `build` directory. Something like this:

**wiki/build.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Mustache = require('mustache');
const myApp = require('../src/index.js');
const inventory = myApp.getInventory();

// Get the Mustache template
const homeTemplate = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/templates/home.mst', 'utf-8');

// Get the fruit with the highest quantity
const topProduct = inventory.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (acc === null || curr.stock > acc.stock) {
    return curr;
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}, null);

// Render the page using your variables
const homeContent = Mustache.render(homeTemplate, { inventory, topProduct });

// Write the file in a build directory
const buildDir = __dirname + '/../build';
if (!fs.existsSync(buildDir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(buildDir);
}

fs.writeFileSync(buildDir + '/home.md', homeContent);
```

And in your `package.json`, add a command to run that script:

```
"scripts": {
    // ...
    "wiki:build": "node wiki/build.js"
  }
```

### Step 3 - Deploy your Wiki pages

Create a script which will upload the pages to your Wiki. This may work as-is without much modification, if you're also using NodeJS.

**wiki/deploy.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Axios = require('axios');
const qs = require('qs');

const config = {
  gitlabBaseUrl: 'https://gitlab.com', // Update this if you're on a private Gitlab
  projectId: process.env.CI_PROJECT_ID, // Provided by Gitlab-CI
  privateToken: process.env.WIKI_DEPLOY_TOKEN, // Added through Gitlab interface
  buildDir: __dirname + '/../build'
};

const axios = Axios.create({
  baseURL: config.gitlabBaseUrl,
  headers: { 'Private-Token': config.privateToken, Accept: 'application/json' }
});

(async function deploy() {
  const existingPages = await getExistingWikiPages();
  const updatedPages = getUpdatedPages();
  // Pages which existed but are no longer in the build (obsolete)
  const pagesToDelete = existingPages.filter(p1 => updatedPages.every(p2 => p2.slug !== p1.slug));
  // Pages which didn't exist before
  const pagesToCreate = updatedPages.filter(p1 => existingPages.every(p2 => p2.slug !== p1.slug));
  // Pages which already exist
  const pagesToUpdate = updatedPages.filter(p1 => existingPages.some(p2 => p2.slug === p1.slug));

  console.log(
    `Found ${pagesToDelete.length} pages to delete, ${pagesToCreate.length} pages to create, ${pagesToUpdate.length} pages to update.`
  );
  for (let page of pagesToDelete) {
    await deletePage(page);
  }
  for (let page of pagesToCreate) {
    await createPage(page);
  }
  for (let page of pagesToUpdate) {
    await updatePage(page);
  }
  console.log('Deploy complete!');
})();

function getExistingWikiPages() {
  return axios.get(`/api/v4/projects/${config.projectId}/wikis`).then(res => res.data);
}

function getUpdatedPages() {
  const files = fs.readdirSync(config.buildDir);
  return files.map(file => {
    const name = file // Remove the file extension
      .split('.')
      .slice(0, -1)
      .join('.');
    return {
      format: 'markdown', // You could make this depend on the file extension
      slug: name,
      title: name,
      content: fs.readFileSync(`${config.buildDir}/${file}`, 'utf-8')
    };
  });
}

function deletePage(page) {
  console.log(`Deleting ${page.slug}...`);
  return axios.delete(`/api/v4/projects/${config.projectId}/wikis/${page.slug}`);
}

function createPage(page) {
  console.log(`Creating ${page.slug}...`);
  return axios.post(`/api/v4/projects/${config.projectId}/wikis`, qs.stringify(page));
}

function updatePage(page) {
  console.log(`Updating ${page.slug}...`);
  return axios.put(`/api/v4/projects/${config.projectId}/wikis/${page.slug}`, qs.stringify(page));
}
```

In the `config` at the top, you need to specify which URL your Gitlab is using. `CI_PROJECT_ID` will be provided by Gitlab-CI itself as an environment variable. `WIKI_DEPLOY_TOKEN`, however, will not. Set it up in step 4.

And in your `package.json`, add a command to run that script:

```
"scripts": {
    // ...
    "wiki:build": "node wiki/build.js",
    "wiki:deploy": "node wiki/deploy.js"
  }
```

**Note:** This example will delete obsolete pages, and update or create new ones depending on files it finds in the build folder and the ones the Wiki already contains. If you want to have attachments as well (images), you'll need to make use of [this API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/wikis.html#upload-an-attachment-to-the-wiki-repository) also.

### Step 4 - Setup a private token `WIKI_DEPLOY_TOKEN`

For this, you'll need to click on your profile picture at the top right corner > **Settings**. Then in the left menu, **Access Tokens**, and create a token with the **api** scope. The name does not matter. Copy this token now, since it will only be shown once.

Then, go to your project. In the menu on the left, click **Settings > CI/CD**. Expand the **Variables** section, and use the previously copied token to create a variable called `WIKI_DEPLOY_TOKEN`, make it **Masked** so that it does not appear in any logs, and **Save variables**:

[image]

This will make that token available only in your pipelines, as an environment variable.

### Step 5 - Create your pipeline

If you don't already have a pipeline, all you need to do is create a `.gitlab-ci.yml` file at the root of your project. Declare a `generate_wiki` stage:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  # - tests
  # - deploy
  # ...
  - generate_wiki

generate_wiki:
  image: node:10
  stage: generate_wiki
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run wiki:build  # build the wiki in a directory
    - npm run wiki:deploy # update it in Gitlab
  only:
    - master # Only when merging or pushing to master branch


# ... rest of your pipeline ...
```

As you can see, we use the commands `wiki:build` and `wiki:deploy` declared in steps 2 and 3.

Now, your project structure should look something like this:

```
/
├───src
│    └── index.js
├───wiki
│    ├── templates
│    │    └── home.mst
│    ├── build.js
│    └── deploy.js
├── .gitlab-ci.yml
└── package.json
```

### Step 6 - Push to master, and enjoy the magic

After pushing, if everything went right, you can click on **CI/CD** in the left menu, and you should see your pipeline running:

[image]

If you click on the little circle, you should see the logs:

[image]

And if you go to your Wiki pages, they should be up to date, automagically:

[image]

Comment: Wow dude, this is awesome. Thanks for putting together such a thorough answer with a great solution. These tools are all pretty new to me - do you have any recommendations on which ones you think I should look into more? For example, should I start looking at Gitlab-CI, or at JS? I really should have elaborated on my intent - I'm hoping to have an SRS page in the wiki, and I wanted to display the largest ID so if somebody wants to add a requirement, they know what number to start with. This code seems like a good start, and also a way to check for duplicate IDs - would you agree?

Comment: "*should I start looking at Gitlab-CI, or at JS?*" It's hard to answer this, Gitlab-CI is just a tool you can use to automate everything, and avoid having to manually generate your pages every time. But the code doing all the work is in JS (in this example, but it could be anything). If you don't know a lot about any programming language (JS being an option), you won't be able to leverage the power of Gitlab-CI which will run your code for you. Looking at this simple demo might give you some ideas, but you'll have to dig deeper to find out what works best for you