# integrating a javascript input text box html in gitlab wiki page?

Tags: javascript, gitlab, jekyll, github-pages, wiki

Very similar to this question:
[Javascript/html in gitlab wiki page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59203694/javascript-html-in-gitlab-wiki-page)

I would like to make a simple html page that has a handy calculator for commonly used tasks.  I understand git-wiki sanitizes out all javascript.  Is there a way to disable this? Or can I i-frame it and host the page somewhere else within github? The demo I'm trying to use is a simple calculator app

https://github.com/Yuvrajchandra/Simple-Calculator

Comment: Is this GitLab or GitHub?  You have tagged both GitLab ***and*** GitHub Pages.

Comment: I think I see the real problem with my example.  It seems I can't add any CSS content to git-wiki  https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/618  This explains that it is likely a security risk. 

I found this page to be most helpful https://talk.jekyllrb.com/t/how-do-i-embed-javascript-in-jekyll/4374/15

Comment: Github, I'll change it