# Is it possible to add a js variable right into an html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is it somehow possible to add `document.referrer` js variable right into the a tag like this?

```
<a href="document.referrer;">Zpět</a>
```

For purposes of code shortening so all the machinery `<script> document.ready ..` doesn't have to be deployed.

EDIT:

For further clarification;
I would prefer something like this to be avoided

```
<a href="#" id="return-back-one">Zpět</a>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        var back = $('#return-back-one')
        back.on("click", function(e){e.preventDefault();history.back(1)})
     });
    </script>
```

in favor of something shorter like

```
<a href="document.referrer;">Zpět</a>
```

or

```
<a href="history.back(1);">Zpět</a>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that?

Comment: there should be the previous url that the user visited so to "send him where he came from"

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, what kind of "machinery" are you talking about?

Comment: Absolutely, thank you very much. 
href="javascript:history.back(1)" does exactly fit

Answer (score 1):

This capability is not built into HTML. You need to use JavaScript to do this.

However you can design your JavaScript in a generic way so that you can have code shortening in future cases. You can do this with regular old JavaScript, or with any JavaScript library.

One regular (ugly and not necessarily secure) JavaScript way might look like:

```
<a data-href="return document.referer || 'https://google.com'" target="_blank">Test</a>

const onDOMContentLoaded = () => {
  const anchorElements = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-href]");
  anchorElements.forEach((anchorElement) => {
    const dataHref = anchorElement.getAttribute('data-href');
    const hrefFn = new Function(dataHref);
    const href = hrefFn();
    if (href) {
      anchorElement.setAttribute('href', href);
    }
  })
  
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', onDOMContentLoaded, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't include variables in tags because html is not a programming laguage, refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035932/how-do-i-use-this-javascript-variable-in-html).